# HP Compaq NW8000 Mobile Workstation does not detect 250 GB Western Digital Scorpio drive

Tags: hard-drive, compaq-laptop

I've installed 250 GB HDD Western Digital Scorpio drive inside my HP Compaq NW8000 Mobile Workstation notebook but it's not detected properly and does not work :/

Tried different jumper combinations but still nothing work. The drive works perfectly in my old Compaq EVO1020V.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Does not work?  Is it the boot drive or a second drive?  IS it detected by BIOS? Any errors?  More info will help here

Comment: It's a boot drive. I've runned Mini Windows XP from Live CD and disk is detected but as a incorrect model WD35**** and can't read any data from it or see partitions. Linux Live CD sees it as 58,7 TB drive and Windows XP installer as 768 GB drive ! Yesterday I've installed Samsung HM160HC and that one works fine. I also got NC8000 at home so I installed the WD out there and it works fine. Both have the latest BIOS. My question is why WD is working ok in NC8000, but not detected in NW8000 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the nw8000 has an obsolete BIOS.

http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-HP-ProBook-EliteBook/what-s-the-largest-capacity-drive-for-the-nw8000-laptop/m-p/1152605/highlight/true#M162362

Comment: It seems that 160 GB for NW8000 is maximum. So I will move my 250 GB to NC8000 ;)

Comment: The link appears to be dead.